# Is there a bug in AutoMapper when mapping an IDataReader to a DTO?

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's the code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<Order>>();
orders = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<Order>>(reader)
```

The result is that the public properties of the DTO are all null.  There is a column in the reader with a name and data type match.  The casing of the name is not exact, but AutoMapper has the code to handle that.

```
var propertyInfo = destinationType.GetProperty(dataRecord.GetName(i), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Unfortunately, it seems that AutoMapper never hits this line of code.  It gets stopped earlier by locating a cached copy of a builder from it's builder cache.

```
            Build builder;
            BuilderKey builderKey = new BuilderKey(destinationType, dataRecord);
            if (_builderCache.TryGetValue(builderKey, out builder))
            {
                return builder;
            }
```

How did it get into the builder cache?  Mysteries...  Help!

Comment: Confirmed.  There's definately a bug in here someplace.

Comment: It also seems to have trouble mapping an IDataReader that contains only GUIDs to a List<Guid>